# Android Widget Manager

Tags: java, android, widget, click

I am working on a widget and did this with help of an tutorial,

basically I have an image view a textview another textview as a widget,

when I click on the last textview a random number appears on the first textview.

Now how could I give the textview just a number without pushing on that button and without that for loop.

So the same functionality without the click / update.

```
public class SimpleWidgetProvider extends AppWidgetProvider {

    @Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
        final int count = appWidgetIds.length;

        RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),
                R.layout.simple_widget);

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            int widgetId = appWidgetIds[i];
            String number = String.format("%03d", (new Random().nextInt(900) + 100));
            String asd = "asch";
            remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),
                    R.layout.simple_widget);
            remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.textView, asd);

            Intent intent = new Intent(context, SimpleWidgetProvider.class);
            intent.setAction(AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE);
            intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS, appWidgetIds);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,
                    0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
            remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.actionButton, pendingIntent);
            appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(widgetId, remoteViews);
        }
```

Comment: Actions in Apps are event-driven. You've said that you want to set a number in the TextView, but you haven't specified when. What action or event will occur which results in the number being set? Or do you mean when the widget is created?